# Using Origin with proxy server

Tags: origin

I am trying to use origin in my university, but the problem is all the traffic through university's wifi is directed through a proxy server which requires my username and password.

There is no such option in origin to enter proxy details. Then how can i access origin in my university? Is there any software that can set some kind of proxy or anything?

Comment: I only have experience with the university I attended, but the fix there was that most programs inherited proxy data from Internet Explorer. Ask whoever's supposed to be supporting that network.

Comment: It should retrieve the proxy from internet explorer, but it does not in my case.

Comment: There exists lots of these tools out there. Take a look at proxyfire for example and it's alternatives. This should solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that others are having this problem as well.  And, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of solutions out there:

http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/9046203.page

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2040815/connect-steam-origin-proxy.html

And the [official statement from EA](http://help.ea.com/en/article/can-i-use-origin-with-a-proxy-server/) on this matter doesn't help:

> The use of proxy servers is not supported by the Origin client, and our advisors are unable to assist players using proxy servers in conjunction with Origin.
>
> If you run into any issues with Origin while using a proxy server, try disabling your proxy's functionality and attempting again.

You still should be able to play your games without a connection to Origin (assuming it's not an MMO, or something that intrinsically requires a connection).  But for things like activation and updates, you may need to go off-campus to connect to another non-proxied network.

Comment: ya, seems to be the only option left.